# why i can't register my Django App models on the admin site?

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-models

but i see Groups and Users model by default if i try to register my model in app/admin.py using admin.site.register(model_name) if i try to registered the default Groups and User it will also not working  for me.

## CODE

## Directory 'app/admin.py'

```
from django.contrib import admin
from app.models import Contact
admin.site.register(Contact)
```

## Directory 'app/models.py'

```
from django.db import models

class Contact(models.Model):
     name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
     gender = models.CharField(max_length=50,choices=('female','Female') 
              ('male','Male')))
     email = models.EmailField(max_length=100)
     info = models.CharField(max_length=100)
     phone = models.IntegerField()
     image = models.ImageField(blank=true,upload_to='images/')
     date_added = models.DateField(auto_now_add=True)

     def __str__(self):
         return self.name
```

Comment: Are you add your `app` to `INSTALLED_APPS` in `settings.py`?

Answer (score 0):

Change the import from "app.models" to just ".models"  because they are in the same directory  and see